Display the average number of days between a customer's last and second to the last transaction
Dataset: Fact_Centre_Txn



Centre_Id
Cust_Id
Visit_Date
Transaction_Id
Transaction_Amt




N01
1
2022-03-10 03:51:00.000
5
-298


N01
1
2022-03-24 00:17:00.000
23
97


N01
1
2022-04-11 03:52:00.000
29
-66


N01
1
2022-03-22 13:23:00.000
31
252


N01
1
2022-03-29 22:27:00.000
58
148


N01
1
2022-03-02 15:10:00.000
66
-75


N01
1
2022-03-12 13:17:00.000
71
121


N01
1
2022-03-18 05:01:00.000
80
0


N01
1
2022-03-19 00:59:00.000
149
0


N01
1
2022-03-02 16:19:00.000
180
-407


N02
2
2022-03-05 21:08:00.000
190
241


N02
2
2022-04-11 13:24:00.000
148
-202


N02
2
2022-04-09 02:48:00.000
156
-181


N02
2
2022-02-27 03:53:00.000
78
0


N02
2
2022-04-07 19:44:00.000
75
463


N02
2
2022-04-18 04:46:00.000
87
161


N02
2
2022-03-05 19:04:00.000
143
-109


N02
2
2022-03-27 00:39:00.000
41
369


N02
2
2022-04-03 07:50:00.000
33
0


N02
2
2022-02-05 10:20:00.000
12
-121


N02
2
2022-04-02 16:13:00.000
1
209


N02
3
2022-04-26 06:08:00.000
22
-107


N02
3
2022-04-22 06:08:00.000
22
-107


N02
3
2022-04-13 00:55:00.000
135
-64



...and so on
Desired result:
Number of days between a customer's last and second to the last transaction:



Centre_Id
Cust_Id
Number_of_days




N01
1
12


N02
2
7


N02
3
4



What I got:
Figured out maybe I can use ROW_NUMBER and select the Visit_Date with row_num 2 and 3 (PARTITION BY Cust_Id, ORDER BY Visit_Date DESC) corresponding with the last date and second date to the last transaction. Not quite figuring out what to do next with this:
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Centre_Id, Cust_Id, Visit_Date
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Cust_Id ORDER BY Visit_Date DESC) AS row_num
    FROM dbo.Fact_Centre_Txn
) AS n
WHERE n.row_num = 2 OR n.row_num = 3


Use the lag window function in an inner query. Then in an outer query, use the datediff function. Example:
SELECT centreid, custid, .., DATEDIFF(DAY, last_visit_date, second_last_date)
FROM (
    SELECT centreid 
        , custid
        , visitdate as last_visit_date
        , LAG(visitdate) OVER (PARTITION BY Cust_Id, ORDER BY Visit_Date DESC) AS second_last_date
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Cust_Id, ORDER BY Visit_Date DESC) AS latest_record,....
    FROM table_name
) AS inner_query
WHERE latest_record = 1

